# dplyr adding a label to a group of columns in a table

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, dplyr, xtable

When creating an R markdown report in Rstudio, I would like to make my tables a little easier to understand.  I have looked into kable() and xtable(), but I have not found what I'm looking for (or perhaps haven't understood what I've found).  Here is a sample table that I might include:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(knitr)

mtcars %>% 
 group_by(gear,cyl) %>%
 summarize(count = n()) %>%
 spread(cyl,count) %>%
 kable()
```

Here is the (console) result:

```
| gear|  4|  6|  8|
|----:|--:|--:|--:|
|    3|  1|  2| 12|
|    4|  8|  4| NA|
|    5|  2|  1|  2|
```

In a report, I'd like to include the column name "Cyl" (or even better "Cylinder") above the 4/6/8.  Otherwise, in complex tables, it may not be clear what those values represent.

Specifically: How can I add a row to the start of this table that displays "Cylinder" above the final three columns?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Row and column spanning is not supported by Pandoc's markdown, so in short: you cannot do that without dirty hacks, such as in the CrossTable implementation of `pander`, e.g. `pander(with(mtcars, descr::CrossTable(gear, cyl)))` -- which is a workaround on row spanning. You need colspan here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not specifically what I was looking for, but I settled for just changing each individual column name.  It's basic, but for anyone looking here in the future, my code now looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(knitr)

test <- mtcars %>% 
 group_by(gear,cyl) %>% 
 summarize(count = n()) %>%
 spread(cyl,count)

colnames(test)[2:4] <- paste(c(4,6,8),"Cylinder",sep=" ")

test %>% kable()
```

The resulting table looks like this in the console:

```
| gear| 4 Cylinder| 6 Cylinder| 8 Cylinder|
|----:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
|    3|          1|          2|         12|
|    4|          8|          4|         NA|
|    5|          2|          1|          2|
```

Answer (score 2):

When using HTML as the output the `htmlTable` package provides column grouping:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(htmlTable)

test <- mtcars %>% 
 group_by(gear,cyl) %>% 
 summarize(count = n()) %>%
 spread(cyl,count)

htmlTable(
    test[,-1], # data.frame
    cgroup = c("Cylinders"), # Column group labels
    n.cgroup = c(3), # Number of columns per group
    rnames = test[[1]], # Row labels
    rowlabel = "Gears" # Column header for row labels
)
```

[image: Cylinders vs Gears]

For PDF output `Hmisc::latex` provides a similar syntax (which I unfortunately cannot test by lack of LaTeX on the machine I'm currently working on):

```
library(Hmisc)

latex(
    test[,-1], # data.frame
    cgroup = c("Cylinders"), # Column group labels
    n.cgroup = c(3), # Number of columns per group
    rowname = test[[1]], # Row labels
    rowlabel = "Gears" # Column header for row labels
)
```

If you want MS Word output you're in bad luck as far as I can see at this moment.